# Traveling from Peru to Argentina - where should I buy Pesos?

Tags: money, exchange, argentina, peru

Recently, the value of the Argentinian Peso relative to other currencies has been somewhat erratic and overall dropped by 25-30% (see [chart vs US Dollars](https://www.x-rates.com/graph/?from=USD&to=ARS&amount=1) and set the range to August - September 2018).

Now, I'm currently in Peru (specifically, Lima) and planning to go to Cordoba, Argentina, within the next couple of days. I have some Peruvian Soles (which I would like to get rid of) and some US Dollars.

My question is: Is it better for me, in terms of the exchange rates, to buy Pesos here in Peru, or to do so in Argentina?

Comment: According to an Argentinian I know, the answer depends somewhat on whether you're planning to exchange your foreign currency for pesos at the 'official' rate, or 'on the street' ...

Comment: @brhans: What's better? The official rate or the street rate?

Comment: Apparently your dollars will get you far more pesos on the street in Argentina than they will in a bank (or other 'official' establishment) either in Peru or Argentina.

Comment: With such a volatile situation it is hard to give useful advice. I would exchange the sloes in Peru though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do everything in Argentina. Argentinian Peso is a very volatile currency, and it is prone to "dolar blue" where you can get better rate on the street than in a bank. It doesn't seem to be the case at the moment, tho.

Usually countries do not like to trade volatile currencies so the rate will be real bad. Like, buy at 30 peso per dollar, sell at 40 peso per dollar.

In Argentina you can get rate much closer to the market. Both banks and on-street exchange are available around Plaza San Martín in Cordoba.

As a rule: you get USD outside of Argentina (from ATM for example) and you change them to pesos in Argentina.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: I tried a few currency exchangers, and they would not sell me Argentinian Pesos for US Dollars.

I ended up having less Soles than I thought and I wanted to keep some in case I need them at the airport... and I did. Since tap water in Peru is not potable, and since you can't take bottled water past security, I got taken to the cleaners on a bottle of mineral water past the security check point. Bottom line: I waited with changing the Soles until I got to Argentina; I assume it can't be that bad.